# Is it possible to limit access to records based on profile's region?

Tags: administration, profile, territory-management, custom-profile, authorization

currently system admin profile for all countries USA, India, China.

Can we have custom system admin profile only for one country like usa, in which he isn't able to access the other country records in salesforce. How can this be done? Scope: She can able to perform any operation on her country records but cannot access other country records

Comment: Very good point when you work on a global instance but I don't think so Salesforce is providing that by default. You gonna have to do that through custom profile and not so easy to do because there is a lot of things to consider.

Comment: is this restriction only for a subrange of users or for the entire organisation ? Is this for all objects, or a subrange of objects ?

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't contain a lot of details, but to my knowledge there are 3 high level directions you can investigate in.

1) private sharing models and (apex based) sharing rules. I think this is what you'll want to do.

2) Territory management, this is a [salesforce feature](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_def.htm&language=en_US).

3) multiple salesforce orgs, possible with integration set up where needed, and a master org for reporting. This is a strategy done by HUGE organisations with complex structures and subsidiaries.